# Detecting a shape of a stamp on a b/w document

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on stamp detection and recognition on a document with the help of python opencv. Detecting color stamps was easy, but problem arises when stamps and texts are of same color. The border of stamps are not a line but a sequence of alpha numeric character ( link to example image is below ).

https://www.globalsingapore.sg/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/singapore-disembarkation-card-slip.jpg

Comment: Hi @wasi  , can you tell me how to detect the color stamp from the document image (opencv python)?

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with thresholding and erosion. First remove the red text; then threshold (adaptive would work best).
Then erode the result and look for hexagons.

Comment: yeah, I had already tried that, but the problem is some stamps are over texts and some are partially imprinted means faded (or sometime invisible).

Comment: Please post the worst example :)

Comment: Any idea how to detect stamps if the edges are blurred. Because then you won't be able to get the shape

Comment: Hi @RobAu , I want to detect the stamp from the document can you tell me how to detect it from the document .Please tell me